# C: Having an issue with scope

Tags: c

so I'm studying for a final and we are given this block of codeL

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a;
void addOne(void) {
    a++;
    printf(“W. a = %d\n”, a);
}
int removeOne(int a) {
    int b = a – 1;
    printf(“R. b = %d\n”, b);
}
void swap(int a, int *b) {
    int temp = a;
    a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
int main() {
    a = 5;
    int b = 20;
    if (b > 15) {
        int a = 53;
        removeOne(b);
        addOne(a);
        printf(“X. a = %d\n”, a);
    }
    printf(“Y. a = %d, b = %d\n”, a, b);
    swap(a, &b);
    printf(“Z. a = %d, b = %d\n”, a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

We are instructed to give the outputs of the program.  I'm having trouble with the `addone(a)` where I came up with 54, the correct answer was 6.  Is it 6 because when the function is declared it has the `void` (don't remember the technical term but the information it takes in to the function) rather than something like `int a`?

My more direct question is why does the function take the `a` initialized in the main function rather than the `a` in the `if`?

Comment: That source should not compile.  addOne() does not take arguments.  You sure you got it right?

Comment: It is what the professor sent out as a review for the exam so I would assume so (copy/pasted straight from the review).  I just saw that I flubbed up and didn't put the `#include` in the code block, but besides that it should be solid.

Comment: `<stdio.h>' -- Please post legal C code.

Comment: It's not solid.   Try compiling it on an actual machine.

Comment: sorry, messed up and missed the `#include` in the code block

Comment: "it should be solid" -- it's not. addOne is being passed an argument but it doesn't take one. Fixing this one way or the other gets different results for `a`. If this is really the code that the instructor handed out then the instructor is incompetent.

Comment: Ok, well I don't know what to say, this is straight from the professor and by the cover page was on an actual exam a few years ago.

Comment: This is really weird code. There's 2 functions that seem t like they should be symmetrical, but 1 takes a argument while the other mutates a global. Plus `removeOne`s argument name shadows the global making it unavailable. If you did straight copy and paste it from your professor, I'd be questioning what his intent was here.

Comment: Yeah I'm starting to question it as well.

Comment: If you give the benefit of the doubt that there is a typo and assume the call should be `addOne()` instead of `addOne(a)` then you will get 6.

Comment: Also you have all sorts of illegal characters in this so it can't be copied/pasted and compiled ... those quotes aren't quotes and the minus sign isn't a minus sign. As for Carcigenicate's comment, it's irrelevant ... this is an exam for testing understanding of scope, not an example of working code.

Comment: Thank you Alan, so why would it take the a from the `main` rather than the `if`?

Comment: Because `a` initialized at line 17 is actually the global `a` declared and defined at line 2, the only `a` that `addOne` has access to.

Comment: "so why would it take the a from the main rather than the if" -- Uh, so you don't understand scope *at all*? The top level `int a` is the one visible in addOne.

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot of sense now.  Thank you very much rslemos!

Comment: @AlanAu But we only know that's the error because we know what the answer is supposed to be. If instead we assume that the typo is `addOne(void)` instead of `addOne(int a)` we get a different result.

Comment: @JimBalter True. But what's your point? We are trying to understand and explain what the intention of the question is and help the OP understand scoping. I think we've done that. The OP has enough info now and can clarify with the writer of the question if need be.

Comment: My point is obvious to anyone who isn't making a concerted effort to miss it. As I already said, "Fixing this one way or the other gets different results for a." It's supposed to be a test, but even the most competent programmer only has a 50-50 chance of passing it unless they already know the answer.

Comment: Jim, I'm having a little bit of trouble studying for this class.  I come here just to clarify a few things and figure out where I'm going wrong.  Just trying to get some help, not get talked down to.  Sure the question might have a typo but that's why I'm asking the question.  I'll give you my profs email if you have such an issue over it.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help.  I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the answer is 6:

Note at the top that `a` is declared as a global.  Later, in `main` there is a call to `addOne(a)` inside of a code block.  That code block defines a local variable `a` as well.  The `a` that is passed in that scope is the local `a` (53).  It is passed into a function that accepts an unnamed `void` variable.  In that function, however, there is a reference to `a`.  Due to scoping, this will be the global `a` (5), so `a++` will result in an output of 6.

That is a horrible exam question.